# PCI Scan failing at TCP Source Port Pass Firewall testing

Tags: linux, iptables, tcp, pci-dss

I'm trying to get PCI scan PASS for my website, Scan failing at this step.

`The host responded 4 times to 4 TCP SYN probes sent to destination port 20 using source port 80. However, it did not respond at all to 4 TCP SYN probes sent to the
same destination port using a random source port`

This is my iptable rule.

`Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083
ACCEPT     tcp  --  178.62.35.106        0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4653
ACCEPT     tcp  --  45.58.48.37          0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4653
fail2ban-VESTA  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083
fail2ban-MAIL  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,2525,110,995,143,993
fail2ban-SSH  tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:22
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:4653
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 22,4653
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 80,443
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 21,12000:12100
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 25,465,587,2525
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 110,995
DROP       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 143,993
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3306,5432
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:8083
ACCEPT     icmp --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     all  --  127.0.0.1            0.0.0.0/0
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
ACCEPT     udp  --  8.8.8.8              0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
ACCEPT     udp  --  8.8.4.4              0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:53
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:443`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:80
```

Well… you're allowing all traffic to your machine with a source TCP port of 80. If you don't want that to happen… don't do that.

Comment: If I remove that then curl won't work

Comment: In that case you need to pay more attention to your input and output interfaces, you're treating everything the same.

Comment: can you explain?, I need to allow curl and wget from the server.

Comment: Yes, you are right I don't need tcp spt:80 rule, curl and wget will work using this rule.

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT`